# Radio button checked with JQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

There are 4 radio buttons with Y/N in my page.
Retained - Y / N
Achieved - Y / N

I want to select "Achieved" No automatically whenever I check "Retained" No.  Our business rule is that if we cannot retain it, we cannot achieve it.  So, if Retained is No, Achieved must be forced to select No.

It works only for the first time selection and it checked Achieved No, when the user selects Retained No.

**But after the user has selected "Achieved" Yes, the code is not working anymore.  Even though the user selects "Retained" No, it is not selecting the "Achieved" No.**

I have put the sample code here.

http://jsfiddle.net/thetwai/k7w56gn4/1/

```
$(":radio[id*='rdRetainedNo']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parent().parent().find(":radio[id*='rdAchievedNo']").attr('checked', true);                    

    }
});
```

Actually, in the real page there will be series of lines and radio buttons for each line.  But for the simplicity, I just put single line in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes and you may not give you correct result.

Also you can use `.closest('tr')` instead of `.parent().parent()`, as shown below

**NOTE** - You have missed `<tr>` for second row where below radio button exist, add it to your html.

```
$(":radio[id*='rdRetainedNo']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
       $(this).closest('tr').find(":radio[id*='rdAchievedNo']").prop('checked', true);                    
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k7w56gn4/7/)**

Comment: thanks for the answer... btw, ur demo is not working.

Comment: oh I am sorry, I have added another link by mistake. Please check the updated one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably also want to disable the 'Y' checkbox if you want to force the user to select 'N'

```
$(":radio[id*='rdRetainedNo']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find(":radio[id*='rdAchievedNo']").attr('checked', true);   
        $(this).parent().parent().find(":radio[id*='rdAchievedYes']").attr('disabled', true);

    }   
});
$(":radio[id*='rdRetainedYes']").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find(":radio[id*='rdAchievedYes']").attr('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

This will check the AchievedNo radio aswell as disabling the AchievedYes radio when the RetainedNo is checked. It will also re-enable the AchievedYes if the user changes their mind and selects RetainedYes